# Angular ngFor - Change CSS of the selected row instead of all rows

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-class

This is my code:

TS:

```
  selRow: boolean = false;
```

HTML:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of users" [ngClass]="selRow ? 'selRow' : ''">
  <td class="checkbox-field"><input type="checkbox" (change)="selRow = !selRow" /></td>
  <td class="user-field"> <img [src]="user.userPicture" alt="">
      {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</td>
  <td class="company-field">{{ getCompany(user.companyId) }}</td>
  <td class="email-field">{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td class="roles-field">{{ user.permissionRoles }}</td>
  <td class="edit-field">Edit</td>
  <td class="delete-field"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```css
.selRow {
   background-color: var(--el-lightblue);
}

.selRow .delete-field {
   color: var(--el-red);
}
```

I'd like the above code to change only the checked row by the checkbox, yet it changes the CSS of all rows. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Here is the example:

Before selected:
[image: img-1]

After selected:
[image: img-2]

Comment: It looks like you are using a single variable `selRow` to indicate the state of ALL rows. You need to store the state per row. The simplest that I can think of is to create a dictionary mapping based on the index.

Comment: I've deleted my original answer. Can you please tell me how `selRow` is used in your .ts?

Comment: As @RobinDeSchepper said, it is a boolean. I'll try the dictionary mapping option if nothing else comes up.

Comment: You can extend your `ngFor` statement: `*ngFor="let user of users; let i = index"` to get a number for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are sharing `selRow` for each row, hence when you tick the checkbox in a row, other rows' checkboxes will also automatically checked.

Instead, what you need are:

1. `selRows`: An array to store selected index.
2. `toggleSelectedRows`: An method to add/remove the index from `selRows`.
3. `isSelectedRow`: Check whether the index is added in `selRows`.

```js
selRows: number[] = [];

toggleSelectedRows(i: number) {
  let index = this.selRows.findIndex((x) => x == i);

  if (index == -1) this.selRows.push(i);
  else this.selRows.splice(index, 1);
}

isSelectedRow(i: number) {
  return this.selRows.findIndex((x) => x == i) > -1;
}
```

```
<tr
  *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index"
  [ngClass]="isSelectedRow(i) ? 'selRow' : ''"
>
  <td class="checkbox-field">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleSelectedRows(i)" />
  </td>
  
  ...
</tr>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8qcbpb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition of `[ngClass]` is wrong, as it is true for all of the rows.

if you need to highlight one row at a time, you can save the row index, instead of using `selRow` property.

Like This:

**in TS**

```js
class Component {
   selectedUserIndex: number = null;

   onToggleUser(userInded: number) {
       // unselect the selected row, when the click was on the selected row
       if(userInded === this.selectedUserIndex) {
          this.selectedUserIndex = null;
          return;
       }

       this.selectedUserIndex = userInded;
   }
}
```

**in Template**

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let userInded = index" [ngClass]="userInded ==  selectedUserIndex ? 'selRow' : ''">
  <td class="checkbox-field"><input type="checkbox" (change)="onToggleUser(userInded)" /></td>
  <td class="user-field"> <img [src]="user.userPicture" alt="">
      {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</td>
  <td class="company-field">{{ getCompany(user.companyId) }}</td>
  <td class="email-field">{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td class="roles-field">{{ user.permissionRoles }}</td>
  <td class="edit-field">Edit</td>
  <td class="delete-field"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
</tr>
```

**In the case of multiselection rows:**
**in TS**

```js
class Component {
   selectedUsers: { [key: number]?: boolean } = {};

   onToggleUser(userInded: number) {
       // unselect the selected row, when the click was on the selected row
       if(this.selectedUsers[userInded]) {
         this.selectedUsers[userInded] = false;
          return;
       }

       this.selectedUsers[userInded] = true;
   }
}
```

**in Template**

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let userInded = index" [ngClass]="selectedUsers[userInded] ? 'selRow' : ''">
  <td class="checkbox-field"><input type="checkbox" (change)="onToggleUser(userInded)" /></td>
  <td class="user-field"> <img [src]="user.userPicture" alt="">
      {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</td>
  <td class="company-field">{{ getCompany(user.companyId) }}</td>
  <td class="email-field">{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td class="roles-field">{{ user.permissionRoles }}</td>
  <td class="edit-field">Edit</td>
  <td class="delete-field"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

From the code that you've shown, I'm guessing that "selRow" is a boolean variable in your component.

Since there's always a single instance of that variable, it affects all rows.

You need either a separate variable for each row (perhaps a property in the 'user" if more than one can be selected, or if only one can be selected at a time, a variable that holds the currently selected user.

Comment: Yah! I was already expecting that to be the issue, I just never thought of any other way on how to do it. But thx for the answer!